# cabal build gives parse error, but code works fine in GHCi

Tags: haskell, cabal

My code works in GHCi, but when I try to build the project with `cabal build`, it gives the error 
`parse error on input ‘<-’`

Here's a minimal example:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
    let x = do
        b <- getLine
        return b
    return ()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any tabs? They aren't forbidden, but they can do unpredictable things.

Comment: the snippet as it is copy&pasted into a fresh file works as declared - btw: are you aware that `x` will do nothing?

Comment: I figured it out! See my answer. @PaulJohnson there's no tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that my GHCi is set up to use the `-XNondecreasingIndentation` extension, which can be seen with the command `:show language`

```
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
```

Without this extension this is bad syntax:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
    let x = do
        b <- getLine
        return b
    return ()
```

but this is okay:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
    let 
        x = do
            b <- getLine
            return b
    return ()
```

To fix the problem, add

```
  default-extensions: 
    NondecreasingIndentation
```

to the .cabal file, or if you prefer add `{-# language NondecreasingIndentation #-}` to just this one module. Alternatively, reformat the code as above, or use Haskell98 instead of Haskell2010.